# Distribute python modules as plugins for my own application

Tags: python, plugins, module, distribute

I am developing an application with plugins support. I have designed a plugin manager that loads the modules and do some stuff with them. The problem is that I need distribute those modules through licencing, so I don't want my clients get the code.

What format may I use to distribute the plugins? I was thinking on compressing the plugin folder using Zip format with a password, and that the app uncompresses them on its initialization!

Any Idea?

Comment: License already protects your code, why trying to obfuscate it or to hide it?

Comment: @mguijarr Making it harder to reverse engineer the application could be a reason.

Comment: @mguijarr this is not going to be a world-wide distributed software. I have local customers, so I don't want them to share my code with others (family, friends, etc), and moreover, I don't want them to share the entire software. Therefore I am going to implement some hardware protection, like usb keys. I've found this service in Argentina (where I live in), http://hardkey.com.ar, so I think I am going to contact them!.

Answer (score 1):

you could just do super simple encryption ... that would probably work

```
from itertools import cycle
def encoder_decoder(txt,keyCode):
    return "".join(map(lambda (ch,key):chr(ord(ch) ^ ord(key)),zip(txt,cycle(keyCode))))

my_text = "hello world"
encoded = encoder_decoder(my_text,"my secret key")
print "Encoded:",encoded
print "Decoded:", encoder_decoder(encoded,"my secret key") #note same method and key
```

its basic... but it should thwart your average user